# Maui - LayoutOptions andexpand

Tags: c#, maui

I am creating an application on MAUI, but I have a problem. I'm using andexpand but it keeps telling me it's obsolete, but it still works. I read that Microsoft will ban it. There was an option to use something else that is the same as andexpand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackLayout no longer uses LayoutOptions, the new way is to use a grid and wrap it in that instead:

I had to deal with this issue a couple of days ago when creating an app for a client, here's a XML snippet to show you how to use it:

```
<Grid x:Name="loadingcontrol" Padding="20">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Register" FontSize="Title" />

<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name" />
<Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter First Name"/>

<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Last Name" />
<Entry Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Last Name" />

<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email" />
<Entry Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Email" />

<Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="Phone Number" />
<Entry Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />

<Label Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Text="Password" />
<Entry Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Password" IsPassword="True" />

<Label Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address" FontSize="Title" />

<Label Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0" Text="House/Flat Number" />
<Entry Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter House/Flat Number" />

<Label Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="0" Text="Street Name" />
<Entry Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Street Name" />

<Label Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="0" Text="Postcode" />
<Entry Grid.Row="17" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Enter Postcode" />

<Button Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="0" Text="Create Account" BackgroundColor="#029deb"></Button>
```

If you're looking for a C# version you can use this:

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
    {
    public RegistrationPage()
    {
        var grid = new Grid
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(20),
            RowSpacing = 10
        };

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });

        var titleLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Register",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
        };
        Grid.SetRow(titleLabel, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(titleLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(titleLabel);

        var firstNameLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "First Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(firstNameLabel, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(firstNameLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(firstNameLabel);

        var firstNameEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter First Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(firstNameEntry, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(firstNameEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(firstNameEntry);

        var lastNameLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Last Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(lastNameLabel, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(lastNameLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(lastNameLabel);

        var lastNameEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Last Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(lastNameEntry, 4);
        Grid.SetColumn(lastNameEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(lastNameEntry);

        var emailLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Email"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(emailLabel, 5);
        Grid.SetColumn(emailLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(emailLabel);

        var emailEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Email"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(emailEntry, 6);
        Grid.SetColumn(emailEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(emailEntry);

        var phoneNumberLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Phone Number"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(phoneNumberLabel, 7);
        Grid.SetColumn(phoneNumberLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(phoneNumberLabel);

        var phoneNumberEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Phone Number"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(phoneNumberEntry, 8);
        Grid.SetColumn(phoneNumberEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(phoneNumberEntry);

        var passwordLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Password"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(passwordLabel, 9);
        Grid.SetColumn(passwordLabel
        grid.Children.Add(passwordLabel);

        var passwordEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Password",
            IsPassword = true
        };
        Grid.SetRow(passwordEntry, 10);
        Grid.SetColumn(passwordEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(passwordEntry);

        var addressLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Address",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
        };
        Grid.SetRow(addressLabel, 11);
        Grid.SetColumn(addressLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(addressLabel);

        var houseNumberLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "House/Flat Number"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(houseNumberLabel, 12);
        Grid.SetColumn(houseNumberLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(houseNumberLabel);

        var houseNumberEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter House/Flat Number"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(houseNumberEntry, 13);
        Grid.SetColumn(houseNumberEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(houseNumberEntry);

        var streetNameLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Street Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(streetNameLabel, 14);
        Grid.SetColumn(streetNameLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(streetNameLabel);

        var streetNameEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Street Name"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(streetNameEntry, 15);
        Grid.SetColumn(streetNameEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(streetNameEntry);

        var postcodeLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Postcode"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(postcodeLabel, 16);
        Grid.SetColumn(postcodeLabel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(postcodeLabel);

        var postcodeEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Postcode"
        };
        Grid.SetRow(postcodeEntry, 17);
        Grid.SetColumn(postcodeEntry, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(postcodeEntry);

        var createAccountButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Create Account",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#029deb")
        };
        Grid.SetRow(createAccountButton, 18);
        Grid.SetColumn(createAccountButton, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(createAccountButton);

        Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = grid
        };
    }
}
```

Obviously this is just an example from my previous project. you'll have to change it for your own needs, but it should give you an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.layoutoptions.centerandexpand?view=net-maui-7.0) you will see this

> The StackLayout expansion options are deprecated; please use a Grid
> instead.